# React Native MSAL - SSO does not work from Native to Web - iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-ad-msal

We are developing two new react native apps, and need to integrate Azure AD authentication at both the places. We also have existing web apps that are Azure AD enabled and the user can open the web links from our (new) native apps.

We have decided to use MSAL library (react-native-msal) to implement the authentication part mainly to support SSO between the native apps + the web apps that we open in the Safari browser.

We have followed all the steps that the react-native-msal library suggests and are able to achieve SSO between the two native apps.

However, when I login to one native app, and try to open the web app link using react linking, the web app prompts for the login credentials.

**Note:**
For authenticating user through native app, we are using "**Authentication Session**" with "**prefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession = false**" which ideally should share the SSO cookies with the Safari browser.

But clearly, this does not seem to work.

I would like to get some understanding on this problem and find out if others are facing this issue too? or is it just us?

Comment: Hello, so i see that u resolved this using a physical device, i have the same issue as u but also on a real device cookies/session are not shared with safari. my question is did u have a custom domain for the sso azure b2c or ur using the default one xxxx.b2clogin.com ?

Comment: please can i have a response

Comment: We use login.microsoftonline.com. Our apps do not use b2c. One thing to note here is that, webview, in-app browser (safari) and safari browser do not share sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out to be a problem with the simulator. This functionality works only on the physical devices (iPhone/iPad) and not on the simulators.

This should have been documented in the react-native-msal's document though.

Comment: OMFG thank you, been pulling my hair out for a week!!!

Comment: have u guys used a azure b2c custom domain for the app or the default one xxx.b2clogin.com ?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need a preferred user token and send it along with the login request. For capturing the details of the user at the same time I suggest storing the details in the domain wide cookies that is known for all applications.

```
  // Store the user details after login
document.cookie = "msal_details=Paul@xyz-corp.com;domain=.xyz-corp.com;path=/"

  // use the user details
 var user = getCookieByName("msal_username"); 
  userAgentApplication.loginRedirect(scopes, "&login_hint=" + user);
```

Lastly, you would need to implement this in your application.

Comment: Thanks @Rutha for your suggestion. However, based on the react-native-msal library document, the SSO functionality should work by following their guide lines and example. But it is not working in this specific case. I shouldn't be making any tweaks to the code to make it work unless there is a bug in the library itself.

Comment: Many browsers today are blocking third-party cookies - cookies on requests to domains that are not the same as the one showing in the browser bar.
This breaks the implicit flow and requires new authentication patterns to successfully sign in users. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-third-party-cookies-spas

Comment: We are already using authentication code flow. After testing on the actual device, we found out that this does not work on simulator. Thanks for your help!